# How do I answer an argument regarding the morality of the prophets marriage?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad, aisha

I were commenting against someone who was talking about the marriage of the prophet pbuh and Aisha peace be upon her too. The person I was commenting against said something like why would God let the perfect model for Earth marry a child when we know in today’s society that it could cause numerous health problems if a man and a young woman were to engage in sexual relationships and that it would leave people committing illegal acts in today’s society. God would’ve known that marrying people significantly younger or older can be bad so why would god set out such a bad example for the humans even though the prophet was supposed to be the perfect example.

Please include Hadith and Quranic verses if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer? **Don't**.

> And it has already come down to you in the Book that when you hear the verses of Allah [recited], they are denied [by them] and ridiculed; **so do not sit with them until they enter into another conversation**. Indeed, you would then be like them. Indeed Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers in Hell all together
>
> <sup>[[An-Nisa' 140](http://legacy.quran.com/4/140)]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> And when you see those who engage in [offensive] discourse concerning Our verses, **then turn away from them until they enter into another conversion**. And if Satan should cause you to forget, then do not remain after the reminder with the wrongdoing people.
>
> <sup>[[Al-'An'am 68](http://legacy.quran.com/6/68)]</sup>

Why are you letting disbelievers tell you what is or is not a good example, instead of putting your faith in Allah and His messenger? Why are you letting yourself be drawn into arguments on sociology and sexual health when you are not knowledgeable in either of those fields?

Instead of arguing without knowledge about topics they understand better than you do, which is exactly what they want you to do, you should just be leaving them to their disbelief; if you want to strengthen yourself in the face of such questions in the future, studying the relevant fields (be they religion or science) with the guidance of a knowledgeable teacher whose goal is spreading knowledge will fare you much better than letting these disbelievers teach it to you, when their goal is simply to spread their own disbelief.

Comment: What if they are literally curious and is evaluating Islam that way.
Similarly to choosing a partner, you would be foolish not to understand it when entering into an agreement

Comment: @SyakurRahman If that were seriously the case, I'd give them pretty much the same advice: Learn about the religion from knowledgeable people whose goal is to spread knowledge, not by paying heed to arguments from disbelievers who are actively trying discredit it. If you are honestly trying to learn from an expert, regardless of topic, it pays to go in with an open mind and actually listen to them, rather than immediately challenging them in ignorance to prove your own misconceptions wrong.

Comment: Well it is things like these that can make someone leave Islam if I don’t understand it give me an understanding. I want to know why something considered so immoral is seen as nothing in our religion.

Comment: @Loading... "Well it is things like these that can make someone leave Islam" <-- You're kinda making my own point for me here. If your iman is so weak that you'd rather put your faith in some random person on the Internet than in Allah and His messenger, then you should be spending far less time listening to them and getting into arguments and more time studying your own religion. Nothing I write here is going to just do that for you.

Comment: Well then again if my iman is weak it is hard to put faith into anything